# Joint Gaussians of three random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance

Suppose that

- $(X,Y)$ are joint Gaussian with $Cov(X,Y)=\theta_1$,
- $(Y,Z)$ are joint Gaussian with $Cov(Y,Z)=\theta_2$.

Are $(X,Z)$ also joint Gaussian? What is $Cov(X,Z)$?

Comment: If you have the marginal pdfs $f_{X,Y}$ and $f_{Y,Z}$, is this enough to determine the pdf $f_{X,Y,Z}$?